# Realisation of the preprojective algebras as $F(\Delta)/T$ over some quasi-hereditary algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quivers, preprojective-algebra

Let $A$ be the Auslander algebra of $K[x]/(x^n)$ for some $n \geq 2$, which is quasi-hereditary with some characteristic tilting module $T$.
Dlab and Ringel showed in their paper "The Module Theoretical Approach to Quasi-hereditary algebras" that that the module category of the preprojective algebra of type A with $n-1$ simple modules is isomorphic to the category $F(\Delta)/T$ of the quasi-hereditary algebra $A$ with $n$ simple modules. Is there an analogue of that for the other preprojective algebras of type $D$ and $E$? That is: Can we realise their module categories as a $F(\Delta)/T$ of some quasi-hereditary algebra (of an Auslander algebra optionally?)?